# EF Core 2.1 Query Types

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I haven't messed about with this yet so am not completely sure of all the possibilities query types have, but it looks like now we can map the results of a stored procedure into a POCO by capturing the results of FromSql queries into a list of POCOs- is that correct?

If so, is it possible to use this technique to map in the results from a stored proc that returns multiple resultsets to their relevant POCOs (as we could do in non-core EF)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [Query Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types) in the EF Core docs and issue [#8127](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8127).

Comment: Hi bricelam, thanks for responding :)

I had a look at the docs, but it doesn't mention anything about stored procs although it does look as though it can use POCOs with raw sql - can it use procs as well in the FromSQL call?

Re the issue 8127, i have read that one in the past but it was opened April last year and hasn't had an update since January this year which is why I am asking the question here now to see if anyone official has any updated information.

Comment: The issue shows how to use a stored procedure and so far the status is that multiple result sets aren't supported. I guess they're not going to update it each week to tell nothing has changed.

Comment: Hi Gert, I understand the issue shows how to use a stored proc, but my question is regarding whether this functionality exists as part of the new Query Types. I would not expect them to update the issue to tell nothing has changed, but thank you for this flippant comment, it has absolutely helped.... With regards to the status of multiple resultsets, are you saying then that this issue is the sole location of any information regarding whether multiple resultsets are going to be implemented in EF core? I am happy if this is the case as it means only one place to look for any status changes.

Comment: Status: On [the backlog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/roadmap#backlog).

Comment: wow, 535 open issues! ok so i won't expect it anytime soon, no worries though, thanks for pointing me in the right direction - i will periodically check the backlog from now on :)